# Change input field to plain text on deselect

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, ajax, html-table

I have a table and when a user clicks on a cell it become editable. I need the editable region to return to plain text with the new value when the user deselects the text field.

Also, could I use AJAX to update a database with the new value while never leaving or reloading the page? Where would that be called?

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TBUM3/1/) of the problem.

This is the jQuery to change the plain text to an input field.

```
/************ Table Editing ************/
$(".editable-cell").click(function() {
    var input = $("<input>", { val: $(this).text(),
                               type: "text" });
    $(this).replaceWith(input);
    input.select();
});
```

This is the HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="editable-cell">This is editable</td>
        <td>This is not.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why not use a `contenteditable` cell?

Comment: Nice! I like that, where would I implement the AJAX?

Comment: In the `blur` handler for the cell.

Comment: contenteditable works differently in each browser.  Not all browsers represent linebreaks the same.  Some will use <p> tags and other <br>.  Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick take at part of your problem:

```
$(".editable-cell").click(function () {
    var control = $(this);
    var input = $("<input>", {
        val: $(this).text(),
        type: "text"
    });
    input.blur(function(){
        control.html(input.val());
    });
    $(this).html(input);
    input.select();
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TBUM3/4/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Will this work in all browsers? Will it not if I use contenteditable?

Comment: I haven't tested it in all browsers, but I don't see any problem with the code.  Basic jQuery.  Contenteditable have a lot of inconsistancies.  I tried using it before, but got weird results.  Then I saw in different browsers the HTML is not rendered the same.  Very difficult to work around.

Comment: Quickly tested in IE - Seems fine!

Comment: If you want to use contenteditable, just be sure that IE doesn't support contenteditable on <TD>.  You will need to put your content inside either a <span> or a <div> and make that contenteditable.
[link](http://www.surrealcms.com/blog/tables-internet-explorer-and-contenteditable)

Answer (score 0):

I think content editable is what you need.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="editable-cell" contenteditable>This is editable</td>
        <td>This is not.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In order to implement AJAX you need `blur` event.

```
$(".editable-cell").blur(function(e) { 
    alert("Do your ajax stuff now!");
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TBUM3/5/)

Comment: I like it, very clean, will it work in all browsers?